# angular 2 checkable dropdown treeview

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am using [ng2-dropdown-treeview](https://github.com/leovo2708/ng2-dropdown-treeview) for a checkable treeview dropdown, this is the [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/1kcbUvNze8HAJ0tN0wsX/) for this package's demo.

Now, I am trying to load my dropdown options from a multilevel array of JSON objects like this:

```
this.leagueList=[
      {"category":[
        {
          "name":"Category 1",
          "id": "01",
          "leagues":[
            {
              "leagueName":"ABC",
              "leagueId":"01",
              "leagueClasses":[
                {
                  "className":"Class A",
                  "classId":"01"
                },
                {
                  "className":"Class B",
                  "classId":"02"
                },
                {
                  "className":"Class C",
                  "classId":"03"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "leagueName":"DEF",
              "leagueId":"02",
              "leagueClasses":[
                {
                  "className":"Class D",
                  "classId":"04"
                },
                {
                  "className":"Class E",
                  "classId":"05"
                },
                {
                  "className":"Class F",
                  "classId":"06"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]}
    ];
```

Please view my code **[HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/rX44c3jj0MOEmGqYUN8M)**  I am getting error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: When you console log your leagueList, it give an object. But when you console leagueList.category is undefined. I'm not an expert in json array but I'll begin to find out how to access category sub object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Because leagueList is an array, not an object, you access to items of array by index first, then access to properties of each item. Example:
leagueList[0].category.

I'm an author of ng2-dropdown-treeview. Post any question about it and I will help you.